# For z in Z(G) show that there exists $\lambda_z$ such that $z.v=\lambda_z v $ for all v in V

Tags: representation-theory

Let $V$ be an irreducible $\mathbb CG$ module. We define $Z(G)$ to be the centre of $G$. For $z\in Z(G)$ show that there exists $\lambda_z\in\mathbb C$ such that $z\cdot v=\lambda_z\cdot v$ for all $v \in V$.

I might have done this but I am not sure if my answer is correct.

Recall Schur's Lemma:

> Let $V$ and $W$ be irreducible $\mathbb CG$-modules.
>
> i) Suppose $\theta \colon  V \to W$ is a $\mathbb CG$-homomorphism.
>   Then either $\theta = 0$ or $\theta$ is an isomorphism.
>
> ii) If $\theta\colon V \to V$ is an isomorphism then there exists $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ such that $\theta(v)=\lambda v$ for all $v\in V$.

So we take a mapping $p\colon  V \to V$ where $v\mapsto  zv$.
This is a $\mathbb CG$ homomorphism.
We use Schur's Lemma, using part (i);
Since $p$ is a $\mathbb CG$ homomorphism we can say that $p=0$ or $p$ is an isomorphism.
If we take $p,g\in G$, then we have $gp=pg$ for all $g\in G$, so $p$ is in $Z(G)$, the centre of $G$. Hence $Z(G)$ is not empty.
So $p$ is an isomorphism.

Next we use (ii).
There exists $\lambda_z$ in $\mathbb C$ such that $p(V)=\lambda_z$ and since $p(v)=zv$, then we have $zv=\lambda_z$ as required.

Thanks

Comment: Your argument is lacking some things. How did you conclude that $Z(G)$ was non-empty? And how did that imply that the map was an isomorphism? The place you need that the element given is in $Z(G)$ is for the map to be a homomorphism in the first place.

Comment: because p exists in Z(G)?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by; The place you need that the element given is in Z(G) is for the map to be a homomorphism in the first place.

Comment: If you take some arbitrary element in $G$, then the map you define from $V$ to $V$ will not usually be a homomorphism of $G$-modules. Your $p$ is not an element of $G$, it is a homomorphism of $G$-modules.

Comment: oh, how would i show that Z(G) is not empty?

Comment: $Z(G)$ always contains the identity. But you do not need that it is non-empty anywhere.

Comment: oh so i dont have to show that Z(G) is non empty? okay then don't know why i thought that..
so I have to show that p=0 or p is an isomorphism and i want to show that p is an isomorphism. how do i do that?

Comment: Consider the similarly defined homomorphism where you pick $z^{-1}$ instead of $z$. What happens if you compose these?

Comment: you would obtain just z?

Comment: Not quite. How did you get that?

Comment: I meant v, wouldn't (p.p^-1) be V->V :v->v?

Comment: Right. So what does this tell you about $p$?

Comment: it has a bijective inverse?

Comment: Right, and in particular, it is bijective, as we wanted to show.

Comment: okay so we can conclude that p is an isomorphism. and then we can use part (ii) of Schur's Lemma to say that There exists λz in C such that p(V)=λz and since p(v)=zv then we have zv=λz as required. Or does this need work too?
Thank you by the way, you're really helping me understand!

Comment: The conclusion looks good. The only part that needs an argument is why this is actually a homomorphism (it is not hard, but you need to check that it is indeed the case, and this is where you will need that $z\in Z(G)$).

Comment: oh we need to prove it is a CG homomorphism as well rather than just stating it?

Comment: Yes, precisely (unless this has already been proven previously of course).

Comment: so i have to show p(g·v)=g·(p(v)), for all g∈G,v∈V. or p(g·z)=g·(p(z)), forallg∈G,z in Z(G).

Comment: Not quite. The first part was right, but you wrote up the definition of $p$ incorrectly.

Comment: what do you mean the definition of p incorrectly?

Comment: Once you include the $z$, there should no longer be a $p$ (applying $p$ is multiplication by $z$).

Comment: I am confused, so i have to show p(g·v)=g·(p(v))?

Comment: Right, that is what you need to show.

Comment: is it enough to say
p(g.v)=(v.g)->z(v.g)
and
g.(p(v))=g.(zv)=z(v.g)=p(g.v)?

Comment: What do you mean by $v.g$? $G$ only acts from the left here. You have $p(v) = z.v$, so you need to show that $z.(g.v) = g.(z.v)$ for all $g\in G$.

Comment: im sure this is simple but ive completely confused myself now..

Comment: okay i see how you get to z(g.v) and g(zv) but how do you show they are the same?

Comment: Recall that by definition, we have (for all $h$ and $k$ in $G$), $h.(k.v) = (hk).v$.

Comment: so then you would get (zg).v and (gz).v?

Comment: Right. Now recall what we had assumed about $z$.

Comment: its in the centre Z(G)?

Comment: Yes, which means that we have what relationship between $zg$ and $gz$?

Comment: zg=gz oh i see!

Comment: Great (those moments of realization are always really nice).

Comment: yeah, thanks ever so much! i dont suppose you could have a look at another of my questions, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/700219/suppose-that-v-is-a-2-d-fg-module-and-that-there-exists-g-h-in-g-v-in-v-such-th

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show that for every element in the centre $z\in Z(G)$ there is a complex number $\lambda_z\in \mathbb C$ such that $zv = \lambda_zv$ for all $v\in V$, you should take the following steps. (I can see them from in your argument but I want to help you structure them a bit.)

1. Show that $p(v) := zv$ is indeed a $\mathbb CG$ homomorphism. ($z$ being in the centre is playing a central role here)
2. Assume $p$ is zero. This yields $\lambda_z =0$.
3. Assume $p$ is not zero. Use (ii) from Schur's Lemma.